# Laravel: Add unique validation rule for associative array input request on update operation

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I am doing update operation and have an input request like below:

```
array:1 [
  "buildings" => array:3 [
    0 => array:4 [
      "item_id" => 6
      "florida_number" => "1006"
      "serial_number" => "1002"
      "building_id" => 6
    ]
    1 => array:4 [
      "item_id" => 7
      "florida_number" => "1007"
      "serial_number" => "1002"
      "building_id" => 7
    ],
    .....
    .....
  ]
]
```

Now I want to apply unique validation rule on ***serial_number*** field which is stored in ***items*** table in database.
The thing I need to take care of here is to ignore the current item id while checking uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to add a rule like below to your form request:

```
return [
            'buildings' => 'array',
            'buildings.*' => Rule::forEach(function ($value, $attribute) {
                return [
                    'serial_number' => 'unique:items,serial_number,'. $value['item_id']
                ];
            })
      ];
```